# How can I train a Convolutional Generative Adversarial Network in Tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow.js, generative-adversarial-network

I'm following the tutorial over at https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan.
While the tutorial is written in python, I'm trying to implement it using tensorflow.js on node.js.
I've been able to figure out how to translate most of the methods used, except when it comes to actually setting up the following training step procedure.

```py
# Notice the use of `tf.function`
# This annotation causes the function to be "compiled".
@tf.function
def train_step(images):
    noise = tf.random.normal([BATCH_SIZE, noise_dim])

    with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
      generated_images = generator(noise, training=True)

      real_output = discriminator(images, training=True)
      fake_output = discriminator(generated_images, training=True)

      gen_loss = generator_loss(fake_output)
      disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)

    gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
    gradients_of_discriminator = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)

    generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, generator.trainable_variables))
    discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, discriminator.trainable_variables))
```

Clearly not everything here is translatable to tensorflow.js.
So far I am unable to figure out how to obtain the gradients and apply them to the optimizer.
I have tried to use the `tf.grad` & `tf.grads` functions, but to no avail.
Here's what I have so far:

```js
function trainStep(images) {
    const noise = tf.randomNormal([BATCH_SIZE, noiseDim]);

    const generated = gen.apply(noise, { training: true });
    const realOut = dis.apply(images, { training: true });
    const genOut = dis.apply(generated, { training: true });

    const genLoss = generator.loss(genOut);
    const disLoss = discriminator.loss(realOut, genOut);

    // now what?
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this in tensorflow.js than the guide shows?
I would appreciate it if anyone has any resources to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this official codelab for TensorFlow.js:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tfjs-training-classfication/index.html

This is for MNIST but once you learn this you can apply to your own dataset.